# Load Linux from GRUB menu

Tags: linux

My OS is CentOS 6.6. I am trying to practice with loading Linux from GRUB menu using copy of main kernel.
I made directory /boot/boot2. Then I put there the copy of kernel(vmlinuz-2.6.32-504.12.2.e16.i686 and initframs-2.6.32-504.e16.i686.img) from directory /boot and renamed them into new_init and new_vmlinuz.
Next step was reboot. Then I went to the main menu of Grub loader using `ESC`and`c` before boot.
At first I used this command:

```
grub> find /boot/grub/stage2
```

And I had this: `Error 15: File not found`.
Then I tried `grub> kernel /boot/boot2/new_vmlinuz` and again I had this annoying `Error 15: File not found`. I would really appreciate for any advice how to do a proper boot from GRUB LOADER.